# What are batmp and %fsp in gcc-generated assembly comments?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I have some code generated by gcc with the options `-march=native -mtune=native -mfpmath=sse -O3 -ffast-math -masm=intel -S -fverbose-asm`, on Core i7 930. Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
mov esi, DWORD PTR [ebp-52] # batmp.271, %sfp
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-28] #, %sfp
add esi, edi    # batmp.271,
add eax, edi    #,
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-108]    #, %sfp
...
cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-100], eax    # %sfp, D.48541
```

What are `batmp.XXX`, `%sfp` and `D.XXXXX` here? How do these names deabbreviate and what do these terms mean?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to tell if you provided the C source for reference.
Apparently `batmp` is "*base address temporary*" used for array accesses. `%sfp` is used as base address for registers spilled to the stack. Unfortunately the compiler doesn't tell us what it spilled even if it is a named local variable, according to my tests. `D.x` is just a general notation meaning "*declaration with uid x*". If it doesn't have a name then it's probably a compiler generated helper variable.